# PyDev using Qt5 to Android application

Tags: python, eclipse, pyqt, pydev

I am curious if anyone has been able to take a PyDev project importing PyQt5 and building that project into a working Android application.  My program runs perfectly in Eclipse Mars 2, but I'm not sure where to go from here.